# How to redirect login to dashboard based on user role in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a project in Angular-11:

auth.guard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
      return true;
    }   
    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
  }
}
```

user interface:

```
 export interface UserInterface {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    access_token: string;
    roles: [];
}
```

authentication service

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserInterface>;
  public currentUser: Observable<UserInterface>;
  constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private config: Config) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserInterface>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): UserInterface {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login({ username, password, rememberMe }) {
    const loginData: OauthInterface = {
      grant_type: this.config.grantType,
      client_id: this.config.clientId,
      client_secret: this.config.clientSecret,
      remember_me: rememberMe,
      username,
      password,
      scope: '',
    };
    const url = `${this.config.apiUrl}/api/oauth/token`;
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(url, loginData, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(user => {
        this.store.dispatch({
          type: '[APP STATE] user details',
          payload: user
        });
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

        this.store.dispatch({
          type: TOGGLE_DIALOGUE,
          payload: null
        });

        this.currentUserDetails().subscribe();

        return user;
      },
        error => {
          // Error Has been captured by interceptor
        }

      ));
  }

  currentUserDetails(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.config.apiUrl}/api/user`;
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(user => {
        this.store.dispatch({
          type: '[APP STATE] set logged in user',
          payload: user
        });
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

        return user;
      },
        error => {
          // Error Has been captured by interceptor
        }

      ));
  }
```

login.ts:

```
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.returnUrl || '/';

  submit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.loading = true;
      const loginData = {
        username: this.loginForm.get('username').value,
        password: this.loginForm.get('password').value,
        rememberMe: this.loginForm.get('rememberMe').value,
      };
      this.authenticationService.login(loginData)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            alert('Ok')
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          },
          error => {
            this.loading = false;
          });
    }
  }
```

There are 3 dashboards (hr-dashboard, account-dashboard, general-dashboard) but several User Roles (Account, HR, ICT, Operation, ...)

I've been on this for days. This is what I want

If the User Role is Account then account-dashboard

If the User Role is HR then hr-dashboard

Else general-dashboard

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: make stackblitz example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a Guard. Here is an example.

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
    ) { }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

        switch(role) {
            case "Role1":
                return this._router.createUrlTree(["account-dashboard"]);
            case "Role2":
                return this._router.createUrlTree(["hr-dashboard"]);
            default:
                return this._router.createUrlTree(["general-dashboard"]);
        }
    }
}
```

You could put this on your "general-dashboard" route. Then just navigate all users to this whenever you want to load the dashboard page & this guard will redirect them to the correct page depending on their user role.